# What button is this button called?

Tags: html, css, button

[image]

Does anybody know what is this button called? I want to use this button to do a frequently asked questions page.

Comment: you can right-click on that particular element and select the Inspect option. If you don't know how to do, please provide the url to us, thanks!

Comment: From my guess, it is the ```plus-circle``` and ```minus-circle```  icon from font-awesome https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/plus-circle?style=regular, https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/minus-circle?style=regular

Comment: its an fontawesome icon

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plus-circle icon with the class `fa fa-plus-circle` by importing the font awesome link to your html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Used on a button:</p>
<button style="font-size:24px;background:transparent;border:none"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
</body>
</html>
```